# Check if ArrayList contains any letters

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Is there away to have an `ArrayList` built on a `String` that the user entered and check if it contains any letters at all?

For example:

```
[1, 2, +, 4, 5, /]
```

would return `true`

```
[1, 2, b]
```

would return `false`

Comment: Question is not clear!

Comment: Write your own loop, break it as soon as you find a letter and return false, else return true.

Comment: You can check with a regular expression like [a-zA-Z]

Comment: Probably you can iterate each element in array list and if the ascii value of the element is withing the alphabet range return false.

Comment: *"`[1, 2, b]`

would return `false`"*  Since when is `b` not a letter?  I think you have mixed up the `true`/`false` since while `+` & `/` are alphabetic, they are **not letters.**

Comment: Since you seem to have abandoned this, I've voted to close..

Answer (score 1):

[Character.isLetter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) determines if a character is a letter or not. So by using this method parse through every element of array and check.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through it and check if the strings contain letters using a regular expression.

```
public static boolean containsLetters(List<String> list) {
    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*")) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```